# Colon on cart page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web-deployment

I'm working on a WordPress site but I'm having problem in cart page for mobile version. I'm getting extra colons, but I can't seem to figure out what's the issue. Any help will be appreciated.

https://haultfoods.com/cart/

[image]

Comment: I have no colons on Firefox 56.0.

Comment: @Dolatabadi still having same issue after disabling Autoptimize plugin.

Comment: @Lofa Problem seems to be in safari, chrome, and IE